# How to view the IMAP flags in an email client?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, thunderbird

We are are setting a the IMAP flags using the Java Mail API. Is there is a way to look at these flags in Thunderbird or other client for debugging purposes?

Comment: You could always use a tool like socat or python and imap lib if you just need to check a few things out. A little understanding if RFC 3501 and you can learn anything with a couple keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks Max. Can you please give an example of the socat? thanks.

Comment: I'll add an answer with a sample session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can learn enough of IMAP to use socat to try yourself.  Here's a sample exchange, I've marked my input with >, and responses with <:

```
$ socat READLINE ssl:imap.gmail.com:993,verify=0,crlf
< * OK Gimap ready for requests from [ip]
> a LOGIN user@gmail.com password
< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH
< a OK user@gmail.com User authenticated (Success)

> a SELECT INBOX
< * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded)
< * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded \*)] Flags permitted.
< * OK [UIDVALIDITY 7] UIDs valid.
< * 836 EXISTS
< * 0 RECENT
< * OK [UIDNEXT 36515] Predicted next UID.
< * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 3346208]
< a OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)

> a FETCH 810:820 (FLAGS)
< * 810 FETCH (FLAGS (\Flagged))
< * 811 FETCH (FLAGS ())
< * 812 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
< * 813 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
< * 814 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
< * 815 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
< * 816 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
< * 817 FETCH (FLAGS ())
< * 818 FETCH (FLAGS ())
< * 819 FETCH (FLAGS ())
< * 820 FETCH (FLAGS ())
< a OK Success

> a LOGOUT
< * BYE LOGOUT Requested
< a OK 73 good day (Success)
```

You will want to at least skim [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), so that you understand UIDs and message sequence numbers, and section 6.4.5 will tell you the various things you can ask for in a FETCH command, such as flags, envelope, etc.

Each command is preceded by an arbitrary tag.  I've used just `a` in the examples.  It's intended to allow pipelining of commands and responses, so that they can be matched up.

The `LOGIN` command is just the username and password, and `SELECT INBOX` chooses the mailbox for the following commands to use.  FETCH takes a sequence list (in the example, I said messages with sequence numbers between 810 and 820, and a list of items to fetch, in this case, just the flags.

Answer (score 1):

Get [Trojitá](http://trojita.flaska.net/), it shows e-mail flags by default. I have no idea how to configure other MUAs to do the same, but I suspect many of them can do this for you as well.